# Deleting entire family of a comment thread

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

Ok, so here is my problem. I am implementing a forum for a client of mine. The code was written years ago and I am working on a delete feature.

Basically, you have your Primary topic. People can comment on that, and comment then on the comments.

The layout would be as such:
[ Main Post ]
  [Comment A - ID 1 - Family Founder]
    [Comment 2 - Parent 1 - ID 2]
    [Comment 3 - Parent 1 - ID 3]
      [Comment 4 - Parent 3 - ID 4]
  [COmment B - ID 5 - Family Founder]
    [Comment 6 - Parent 5 - ID 6]
      [Comment 7 - Parent 6 - ID 7]

The table stores this info as follows:
ID | Parent ID | Topic ID | Comment Content

Currently, it is setup to run with two functions
The first, calls the primary comment (Comment ID 1) and then at the bottom, it calls to see if there are any children of comment ID 1 then loops through them, etc. It is confusing to try to explain.

The problem is, I am unable to keep track of the initial family found (A and B, IDs 1 and 5 respectively).

The only way I can think to do this is to call a function making a multitude of queries on the database until the children count is 0. Storing all the IDs then running a delete query.

Any help is appreciated. If I can explain it better please let me know.

Comment: your tags point to php, mysql and sql-server... Where do you want to solve this? Please edit the tags too...

Comment: It's written in PHP/MySQL, but the logic from any language I believe would work in formulating the solution.

Comment: Well, with SQL Server I'd suggested recursive CTEs or HIERARCHYID, but with mySQL and PHP I have to back out  :-)

Comment: Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

`ParentID` is effectively a foreign key so I'd add a

```
FOREIGN KEY(ParentID) REFERENCES Comment(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

constraint

Comment: I'll look into this as well, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use reoccurrence, e.a. a function that first prints the parrent and then searches all its children and runs himselve for the children.
This would mean that you have the following function calls:

- ShowPost(Main) calling ShowPost 1

  - Showpost 1
  - calling showpost 2, which prints and ends
  - calling showpost 3

    - Showpost 3 calling ShowPost 4, which ends
  - and the showpost 3 ends as well.
  - Then ShowPost(1) ends resulting in
- ShowPost(Main) calling ShowPost 5

  - ShowPost 5 calling ShowPost 6
    etc.

Basically something like:

```
function showPost(int ID) {
  #Find record
  mysql.runquery ...
  #print record
  echo '...';
  #find children
  myql.runquery ...
  while (c=mysql.nextrecord()) {
    showpost (c.ID);
  }
}
```

For deletion something like:

```
function deletePost(int ID) {
  #find children
  myql.runquery ...
  while (c=mysql.nextrecord()) {
    deletepost (c.ID);
  }
  #Then delete himselve.
  mysql.run_sql ('delete from table where id = '.ID);
}
```

Comment: Printing them is not an issue, and basically that's what it does. I am referring to going backwards to delete.

I could do a function
searchParent($id){

      query(select id where parent_id in (ids) )
           loop - store ids in array
                call function again with new ids
                 and keep storing until it returns an empty set
            then delete all with said IDs.. -- I am trying to find a solution that would reduce the server load from calling (potentially 10+ queries) then the delete

Comment: Maybe a dirty solution, but with some RDBMS's you can add a 'on delete cascade' statement, which removes child records on removing parents. I din't know if mySQL can and will perform while doing so, but it's an option te check.

Comment: To further elaborate, I could delete just the parent and none of the children would show on the page. However, that leaves a multitude of data in the database, which is what I was trying to devise a cleaner solution (if possible) than using a new query each time if I was somehow able to keep track of the initial family founder.

Comment: Or you might do the trick I showed above (reoccureence), having a function on the parent looking for children and running himselve on the children, and after that deleting the parent.

Comment: No, I understand what you mean. That is the solution I came to myself. I was just wondering if there was a better way than running a query on each parent ID to get the children, by somehow keeping track of founder of each family. Thanks for the help. I'm researching the cascade